# Modify and debug JDK in Eclipse

Tags: java

I try to do some experiment on JDK in Eclipse, i.e. modify some code and debug it in Eclipse. No need to distribute the code to another environment. Is there an easy way to do this?

I created a java.lang.NullPointerException class in the Eclipse project and add some test code into its constructor and set a breakpoint in it and call new NullPointerException() in main(). No compilation errors reported.

When debug, with JDK8 it reports that "Unable to install breakpoint in java.lang.NullPointerException due to missing line number attributes", breakpoint not hit.

But with JDK9/JDK11 it breaks on my source but it seems to be a bug of Eclipse since the shown source on break is not the one for the underlying byte code which seems to still be JDK binary since with single-stepping it return from the constructor only after one line of code but there are many lines of test code in my NullPointerException constructor.

Is it a bug of Eclipse not to report any error during compilation?

What is expected to happen when you create the same class as some class in a library you reference? What if the library is not JRE/JDK but a user library?

Comment: Eclipse is used by thousands of people and has existed for over a decade. How big do you think the chance is that you are going to be the one to find such a fundamental flaw? Since Java 9 the concept of modules has been added to the Java platform, that may be influencing the change in behaviour you see.

Comment: @Gimby Updated to 2019-09 R (4.13.0) the problem is the same. It is not fundamental since not many people try to override JDK class and debug. Showing the wrong source is high chance to be a bug. I think it's the module that make the difference too but this doesn't answer the question.