# How to repackage JDK9's module

Tags: java, java-9, jlink

I tried to repackage JDK_ROOT\lib\modules in Administrator command line under Windows 10 but get error messages:

```
//first extract modules's content
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\jimage.exe"  extract --dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\modules-extracted" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\modules" 

//try to repackage it and only contains java.base
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\jlink.exe" -v --output "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\modules-repackaged"  --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\modules-extracted" --add-modules java.base

//error:
jdk.tools.jlink.plugin.PluginException: Resource /java.base/java/lang/invoke/BoundMethodHandle$Species_D.class already present
```

According to @Alan Bateman's comment, I removed "BoundMethodHandle$Species_***"(except for _L which is in the source code) in the extracted folder and at this stage it's fine. But when used in Eclipse it says that instrument is need but there is more error:

```
//try java.intrument gives another error
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\jlink.exe" -v --output "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\modules-repackaged"  --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\modules-extracted" --add-modules java.base,java.instrument

//error
Unable to compute the hash of module java.instrument
```

BTW how to repackage JDK so that it contains all modules .i.e. can I use something like "--add-modules *"? And what are the basic modules that a Java HelloWolrd need besides base and instrument?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. What you are using jimage to extract the resources from the run-time image? Some of them are generated at link-time and aren't suited for use as re-input to jlink.

Comment: @ Alan Bateman The purpose is to modify the file "modules" in JDK9, e.g. remove some module/remove some class in a module then maybe after that I can copy and modiry the source of the  removed code to the project to do some experiment on them. This is one potential route to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542460/modify-and-debug-jdk-in-eclipse

Comment: Have you looking at the `java --patch-module`? That is useful for debugging when you want to replace classes in the run-time image. The jlink tool does not have an equivalent option.

Comment: @ Alan Bateman where to put this into an Eclipse debug session?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jmods in the JDK to pack a new JDK

```
//first fork JDK9 or you may won't have an fully functional one
Xcopy /y /q /E /I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4_repack" 

//this is needed if you do this for the second time
rd /S /Q "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4_repack\jdk-9.0.4_repack"

//generate a meta-JDK from jmods
//it's called meta since the output is like a JDK
//but still missing some file to be used alone
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\jlink.exe" -v --output "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4_repack\jdk-9.0.4_repack"  --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\jmods" --add-modules java.base,java.instrument

//combine the meta JDK with the forked JDK 
//(close Eclipse first if it is referencing "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4_repack")
Xcopy /y /q /E /I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4_repack\jdk-9.0.4_repack" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4_repack"
```

Now you can add "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4_repack" as another JDK/JRE option to Eclipse and use it in an application. This JDK only contains modules that you added.

ToDo:

(1) Maybe jlink can generate a full JDK instead of a "meta version" with more correct parameters

(2) Use jmod command to extract some jmods in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\jmods" then edit the content e.g. remove some class then repack the jmods then use them in jlink.